# linux shell wc -c count characters +1

Tags: linux

I used the command wc -c to count the number of characters but it gives me a wrong number, number of characters plus one as an example:

```
echo "k" | wc -c
```

it gives me 2 characters

so why not 1?

Comment: the `-c` option is a byte count, not a character count

Comment: -m, --chars
print the character counts
I also used this same problem

Comment: You're right, I thought unicode was two bytes per char, but it seems ascii letters in uni are still 1 byte.  Curious.  I'm thinking EOL

Comment: yes, I typed "k" in a file and it shows 2 chars i removed it , so it shows 0 curious

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at the help message for `wc`. The `-c` option prints out the number of characters. The `echo` command includes a newline character by default. When `wc` sees the newline it counts it as another character and hence the additional count in your result. You can get around this by using one of the alternatives shown below; `-w` counts the number of words and `-l` counts the number of lines.

```
echo "k" | wc -w 
echo "k" | wc -l
```

You can pipe the output of `wc` to `awk` to get the number of characters excluding the newline characters:

```
wc <filename> | awk '{print $3-$1}'
```

The default output of `wc` with no options prints out the number of newline characters ($1 to awk), number of words and number of characters ($3 to awk) in this order.

Comment: ok, so there's one word and one line, but OP wants to know why there are two characters/bytes

Comment: I want to count number of characters not words nor lines

Comment: ahhh, so you mean `echo -n "k" | wc -c`. That makes sense

Comment: I put the char in file and it gives so that the EOF counted? or new line or what?, As I want to count more than one char

Comment: It worked whit -n but why explain please

Comment: As dinesh said (sorta), echo adds a newline char.  The `-n` option to echo removes it, so only the chars between the quotes are counted.

Comment: cat fileName | sed -n "1p" | wc -c
ok how can I do the same to count the number in first line of letters of this file?

Comment: that sounds like a new question

Comment: thats same one but it gives me plus one char

Comment: @user1865719: `printf` is often preferred before `echo` when consistency is important. It does not print a newline unless specifically asked, so `printf "k" | wc -m` gives `1`, i.e. the number of characters printed. To count characters in the first line of a file, one can do e.g. `$(($(head -1 file | wc -m)-1))` (wrap it in `$(())` to do shell arithmetic to remove the newline count) or even better: use awk and do `awk 'NR==1{print length}' file`.

Comment: + 1 for `wc | awk '{print $3-$1}'` - This is excellent solution. Simple and works for every input, even when there is no terminating newline.

Answer (score 17):

when you `echo "k"`, the `echo` command appends a newline character to whatever you asked it to print out ("k"). You can use the `-n` option to disable this:

```
echo -n k | wc -c
1
```

For viewing that *invisible* character, you could dump stream whith `od` or `hd`:

```
echo k | od -t c
0000000   k  \n

echo k | hd
00000000  6b 0a                                             |k.|

echo k | od -t a -A n
   k  nl
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are using `echo`, which adds a newline to your string. Use `printf` instead:

```
$ echo k | wc -c 
       2
$ printf k | wc -c
       1
```